# Standard zoom view on different mobile devices

Tags: mobile, view, zooming, default, viewport

I'm new to CSS, jQuery etc. I have created a page and I need some guidance.

Currently I am using the metadata viewport tag with a fixed width (since my page is a fixed width at all times) and a initial-scale of 1.

This works very well once you have zoomed out - on all devices. The page renders at the correct scale, everything is great and you can zoom in and back out, and the page stays the same.

The problem is the INITIAL zoom level. When "Initial scale" is set to 1, it will zoom in way too much on phones, which is disturbing to first-time-viewers.

Is there a way to just tell whatever device that is viewing the page, that it should just zoom out as much as the viewport allows it? Like you would do with you fingers as it is right now. Just zoom all the way out and everything is fine... There must be some simple way to accomplish this? I've searched the net as much as I can, and all the solutions I have found either don't work or are really complicated, which seems unnecessary to me!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out, the entire thing was because I had used a comma (,), instead of semicolon (;), to seperate my arguments in the metatag. This caused my first argument, which was width:810px, [next argument] to become invalid, cause the comma was attached to 810px. As soon as I replaced it with a semicolon, everything worked!

Comment: Okay, apparently I'm an idiot. The semicolon doesn't work. I have no idea how this made it work, but now I only have viewport=810 and nothing else, and it works perfectly :/